# java inheritance: distinguish between types of inherited classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an Abstract class, called `A`, and two inherited classes: `B` and `C`. I have a method with a parameter:

```
myMethod (final A a)
```

and I´d like to make different things in case of the type of the instanciated object. How can I do it?

An good alternative is following another design pattern, but I am not allowed to change my code now.

Thanks.

Comment: Does myMethod is part of the A class?

Comment: no, but it should, and in that case should not have any parameter.

Comment: Ok, I see. This is exactly I want to suggest to avoid instanceof at all. Each subclass would just override myMethod and implement its functionality in the way it should. But if you are tied to that particular design, then the solution you have accepted is probably the best :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `instanceof` keyword. For example:

```
if (a instanceof B) {...}
else if (a instanceof C) {...}
else {...}
```

Comment: Whether this is a poor practise is a debate I wish not to enter.

Comment: If C is also a subclass of B you have to have the 'if' testing for C first. I'm not sure if this will matter in your exact case though.

Comment: That is based on semantics of the program...you could say the reverse, that B is a subclass of C.

Comment: True, true, true. You just have to order the 'if's in the right way to detect the classes properly depending on the actual class inheritance in place. That's one of the reasons its a poor practice. Easy to get bugs that are hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

Use `instanceof` operator:

```
myMethod (final A a) {
  if(a instanceof B) {
    //...
  } else if(a instanceof C) {
    //...
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type: " + a);
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that it's a poor practice against all OO principles.